# How can I reset Animated.Value in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my code for animating components based on scrolling:

```
  const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0));
  const scrollYClamped = diffClamp(scrollY.current, 0, topBarHeight);

  const translateY = scrollYClamped.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, topBarHeight],
    outputRange: [0, -topBarHeight]
  });
  console.log('scrollY', scrollY, scrollYClamped);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('in use effect');
  }, []);

  const handleScroll = Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          contentOffset: { y: scrollY.current }
        }
      }
    ],
    {
      useNativeDriver: true
    }
  );
```

The thing which I want to achieve is reset the `scrollY` to the initial value whenever a method is called. Something like:

```
const resetValue = () => { scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)); }
```

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: You provided a possible solution. What's the problem with it?

Comment: @isherwood because it throws a following error: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `setValue` method on the animated value. Something like the following should work for you:

`scrollY.current.setValue(0);`

You can read more about setValue here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/animatedvalue#setvalue

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is absolute .To reset the animates value you have to use **setValue** method in your animated vakue. Like

***scrollY.current.setVAlue(0);***

If you like to learn more about animated and setValue refer [React Native Animated.](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animatedvalue#setvalue)